# Is this the case that $P_n< Q_n$, for all $n>1$?

Tags: order-theory

From the values available in OEIS, it appears that $P_n <Q_n$, for all $n>1$, where $P_n, Q_n$ represent respectively the numbers of partial orders and quasiorders on $n$ elements.

Is there a way to prove/disprove this?

Comment: Partial order is defined by reflexivity, antisymmetricity and transitivity; quasiorder is defined by reflexivity and transitivity. Since the condition for being partial order is more strict, the number of partial orders should be smaller.

Comment: How did I miss that? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why is the limit of the ratio $\frac{P_n}{Q_n}\to 1$ as $n\to\infty$?

Comment: That technically only proves $\leq$, not $<$. To prove $<$, you also have to, say, show an example of a non-partial quasiorder for every $n$.

Comment: Yes. What about the strict inequality?

Comment: Yes, one should exhibit some example. Thanks

Comment: The relation $\{(1,2),(2,1),(1,1),(2,2)\}$ is a quasiorder, but not a poset. This justifies the strict inequality.

Comment: It justifies the strict inequality for $n=2$. It isn't difficult to generalise, but that doesn't mean you can avoid it.

Comment: In general, we may take $\{(1,2),(2,1),(x,x)|x\in A\}$.

Comment: That's much better. Any equivalence relation is a quasiorder, but many equivalence relations (like that one) aren't partial orders. That's a very prolific source of counterexamples.